# Graph of the linear fit with the experimental points of different colors and numbered

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I would like to graph the following points and their respective line of fit on the same graph, but I would like to know if it is possible that the points are colored with different colors just as in the graph that I annex.

[image: expected colors]

The graph that I managed to obtain was:

Show[p1, p2]

[image: common graph]

```
p1 = ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {16, 1.09}, {17, 1.08}, {18, 1.2}, {19, 
1.27}, {20, 1.56}, {21, 1.42}, {22, 1.47}, {23, 1.53}, {24, 
1.65}, {25, 1.67}, {26, 1.73}, {27, 1.8}, {28, 1.87}, {29, 
2.91}, {30, 2.02}, {31, 2.07}, {32, 2.13}, {33, 2.17}, {34, 
2.27}, {35, 2.33}, {36, 2.37}, {37, 2.41}, {38, 2.53}, {39, 
2.46}, {40, 2.67}, {41, 2.73}, {42, 2.8}, {43, 2.83}, {44, 
2.93}, {45, 3}, {46, 3.07}, {47, 3.5}, {48, 3.2}, {49, 3.29}, {50,
 3.33}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]

p2 = Plot[{0.0677 x}, {x, 0, 65}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

I already graphed the points in a very common way but I would like the points to look colored like the previous graph. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 0}, {16, 1.09}, {17, 1.08}, {18, 1.2}, {19, 1.27}, {20, 
    1.56}, {21, 1.42}, {22, 1.47}, {23, 1.53}, {24, 1.65}, {25, 
    1.67}, {26, 1.73}, {27, 1.8}, {28, 1.87}, {29, 2.91}, {30, 
    2.02}, {31, 2.07}, {32, 2.13}, {33, 2.17}, {34, 2.27}, {35, 
    2.33}, {36, 2.37}, {37, 2.41}, {38, 2.53}, {39, 2.46}, {40, 
    2.67}, {41, 2.73}, {42, 2.8}, {43, 2.83}, {44, 2.93}, {45, 
    3}, {46, 3.07}, {47, 3.5}, {48, 3.2}, {49, 3.29}, {50, 3.33}};

p1 = ListPlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> Hue];

p2 = Plot[{0.0677 x}, {x, 0, 65}];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Or colored according to the x-coordinate, instead of the y-coordinate:

```
p1b = ListPlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]]];
Show[p1b,p2]
```

[image]

Or perhaps

```
p1c = ListPlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Show[p1c, p2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make each point a separate data set by mapping `List` onto the data. However, the colors cycle every 15 data points.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[List /@ {{0, 0}, {16, 1.09}, {17, 1.08}, {18, 1.2}, {19, 1.27}, {20,
      1.56}, {21, 1.42}, {22, 1.47}, {23, 1.53}, {24, 1.65}, {25, 1.67}, {26, 
     1.73}, {27, 1.8}, {28, 1.87}, {29, 2.91}, {30, 2.02}, {31, 2.07}, {32, 
     2.13}, {33, 2.17}, {34, 2.27}, {35, 2.33}, {36, 2.37}, {37, 2.41}, {38, 
     2.53}, {39, 2.46}, {40, 2.67}, {41, 2.73}, {42, 2.8}, {43, 2.83}, {44, 
     2.93}, {45, 3}, {46, 3.07}, {47, 3.5}, {48, 3.2}, {49, 3.29}, {50, 3.33}},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed"],
 Plot[{0.0677 x}, {x, 0, 65},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[.7]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) to vary the color as a function of x (`#1`) or y (`#2`).

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {16, 1.09}, {17, 1.08}, {18, 1.2}, {19, 1.27}, {20, 
    1.56}, {21, 1.42}, {22, 1.47}, {23, 1.53}, {24, 1.65}, {25, 1.67}, {26, 
    1.73}, {27, 1.8}, {28, 1.87}, {29, 2.91}, {30, 2.02}, {31, 2.07}, {32, 
    2.13}, {33, 2.17}, {34, 2.27}, {35, 2.33}, {36, 2.37}, {37, 2.41}, {38, 
    2.53}, {39, 2.46}, {40, 2.67}, {41, 2.73}, {42, 2.8}, {43, 2.83}, {44, 
    2.93}, {45, 3}, {46, 3.07}, {47, 3.5}, {48, 3.2}, {49, 3.29}, {50, 
    3.33}},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#1] &)],
 Plot[{0.0677 x}, {x, 0, 65},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[.7]]]
```

[image]